# MultiBinding Convert Back function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to convert some units.How should the Convertback function work with the following.
Got the following XAML. The Tag is set to a unique object in my ViewModel.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Tag ="{Binding MyObject1}" Style ="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Tag ="{Binding  MyObject2}" Style ="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
```

with this style ...

```
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EditUnitsConverterEx}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag"/>
                        <Binding Path="IsMetric"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

with this converter ...

```
class EditUnitsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    MyObject item; // 
    bool IsMetric; // bool telling me what units the system is in

    public object Convert(object[] values,
                    Type targetType,
                    object parameter,
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string sResult = "";

        if (values[0] != null && values[1] != null)
        {
            item = values[0] as MyObject;
            IsMetric = (bool)values[1];

            sResult = item.Value;

            switch (item.Type)
            {
                case UnitsType.Distance:
                case UnitsType.Speed:
                    if (IsMetric && !item.UnitsAreMetric)
                    {
                        double dValue;
                        double.TryParse(item.Value, out dValue);
                        dValue = dValue * 25.4;
                        sResult = dValue.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (!IsMetric && item.UnitsAreMetric)
                    {
                        double dValue;
                        double.TryParse(item.Value, out dValue);
                        dValue = dValue / 25.4;
                        sResult = dValue.ToString();
                    }
                    break;

                case UnitsType.Weight:
                    break;


                case UnitsType.Force:
                    break;

                default:
                    sResult = item.Value;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return sResult;

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value,
                                Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();

       // Need to know here what Object/Tag item I am dealing with ?????

     }

}
```

Any ideas with sample code. Thanks for the help !

Comment: I'm not sure that you can reconstruct the two objects that your multi-converter is aggregating if you are removing the information about the measurement unit from the converted value. How do you expect this to work?

Answer (score 6):

Your `ConvertBack` methods needs to convert from a string to an array where the first item is a `MyObject` and the second one is a `bool`.

**Sometimes** one **cannot have a two-way conversion** and therefore does not implement the `ConvertBack` method meaning you only have one-way bindings.

If you can convert it then you should implement it. 
I can't really see how that's possible with your `Convert` output.

*How can i tell that this converted string is now in the metric ou non-metric system?*

For a sample implementation look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Did you understand this and did it work? If só you should accept this answer